# Responsive QGIS main window while running a QGIS plugin with GUI

Tags: qgis-plugins, gui, qthread

I'm writing my first QGIS plugin (QGIS version >= 3.18). I created a GUI with QT Designer and then a basic python code to load plugin when QGIS starts:

file **`__init__.py`**:

```
def classFactory(iface):
    from .myFirstPlugin import MyFirstPlugin
    return MyFirstPlugin(iface)
```

file **`myFirstPlugin.py`**:

```
import os
from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction,QDialog

class MyFirstPlugin(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,iface):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.iface = iface
        ui_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'myfirstplugin_dialog_base.ui')
        uic.loadUi(ui_path,self)

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction('My First Plugin',self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'myfirstplugin.png')
        self.action.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&My First Plugin',self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removePluginMenu('&My First Plugin',self.action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def run(self):
        self.setModal(True)
        self.show()
        self.initialize()
        result = self.exec_()
        if result == QDialog.Accepted:
            pass
```

where `myfirstplugin_dialog_base.ui` and `myfirstplugin.png` are respectively the GUI created with **QT Designer** and the icon that appear on the button in the toolbar of QGIS main window. The plugin starts regularly without any problems.

Now, I want to run the plugin and keep QGIS main window responsive. I found a lot of solutions about keeping QGIS plugin GUI responsive while running process, but nothing regarding QGIS main window. From what I've read, the correct way is to start the plugin on a separate thread (for example using `QThread`), but I just don't know how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was simpler than I expected. After several attempts to start the plugin on a separate thread, all of which failed, I simply modified the instruction

```
self.setModal(True)
```

to

```
self.setModal(False)
```

in this way, the main QGIS window remains responsive after the plugin GUI is started.